# Filter Search Results by two or three tags

Tags: support, tags, search

Is there a way to get a list that combines two or more tags without all of the questions having to be tagged with both tags?  For example, on stack overflow i tend to look at the sql-server tag a lot, but not all sql server questions get that tag.  What i'd really like is a list of unique questions tagged with sql-server, sql-server-2005or sql-server-2008.  Is there a way to do this?  If not, can we implement a way to do this?

Comment: I think this actually used to work, I've got a collection of feeds, on of which points to `http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/emacs+or+elisp+or+emacs-lisp+or+dot-emacs` that I used to keep up with, in this case, emacs questions. The feed doesn't seem to have been updated since October 29, 2010.

Comment: I should point out, that going to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/?tagnames=emacs+or+elisp+or+emacs-lisp+or+dot-emacs&sort=active` works, and has the standard rss link at the bottom, but that link goes to a 404.

Answer (score 2):

There is a data.SE query to do this for two tags:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/183621/filter-unanswered-questions-by-two-tags

which can be forked to work for three and base results on a specific state.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, a tag wildcard will do what you want. For your given example, [`[sql-server*]`](//stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql-server*]) is the way to go; the `*` expands to all tags that fit that pattern.